# Cant get @media screen to work

Tags: html, css

Earlier I asked question about my profile design, I am said I was not gone use the same design on mobile phone but I've changed my mind, howere i use `height:10%;` on the banner in the main style but when using `@media all and (max-width:1024;){}` and having same class but with `height:30%;` it wont change. I have a different css where I do the same thing but there it works (most of the times).

html:

```
<?php if($user_visible == 'a'){ ?>
  <!--Profile picture, banner, and main information-->
    <div class="profile-wrapper">
      <?php if(isset($user_avatar)){ echo'<img class="banner" src="/assets/images/banner/'.$user_banner.'" />'; }else{ echo'<img class="banner" src="/assets/images/banner/default.png" />'; }?>
      <!--profile picture-->
      <?php if(isset($user_avatar)){ echo'<img class="avatar" src="/assets/images/users/'.$user_avatar.'" />'; }else{ echo'<img class="avatar" src="/assets/images/users/default.png" />'; }?>

      <!--user information-->
      <div class="user-information">
        <p><?php echo $user_name; ?><br />
        <?php echo $user_firstname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $user_lastname; ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
/* **************************************************************************************
///////////////////////Main Style////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
************************************************************************************** */
@media all and (min-width:1024px;) {
    .avatar {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius:5px;

        margin-top:-10%;
        margin-left: 5%;

        width:15%;
        height:auto;
    }

    .banner {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius:5px;

        margin-top: 20px;

        height:10%;
        width:100%;
    }

    .profile-wrapper {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:90%;
    }
}


/* **************************************************************************************
///////////////////////Tablet////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
************************************************************************************** */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .banner { height:30%; }
}



/* **************************************************************************************
///////////////////////Phone/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
************************************************************************************** */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .banner { height:30%; }
}
```

Comment: I notice i forgot to remove the `@media` under main style, that was a part of the last test I did before i came here

Comment: Remove that ; from your media query, it should be (min-width:1024px) not (min-width:1024px;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the most universal media queries out there as they will help you to cover most of the different screen sizes decently:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

So try these media queries for your banner:

```
    @media(min-width:992px){
    .banner {
       height: 30%;
    }
}
          @media(min-width:1200px){
          .banner {
          height: 10%;
        }
}
```